# Find the parameterization of shadow cast on plane

Tags: geometry, 3d, parametric

> Suppose there is a light source at $(0, 0, 8)$. Consider the line segment $r(t) = \langle 3-3t, 1+t, 2+2t\rangle, 0\le t\le1$. Find the shadow cast by the line segment on the plane $x+y-2z=8$

I have never encountered this type of problem before, but nevertheless I gave it a try. I would imagine that we would first find the plane that the point's shadow draws. This seems to be the plane passing through $(3, 1, 2)$, $(0, 2, 4)$, and $(0, 0, 8)$. This gives me the plane equation $4x+6y+3z=24$.

The intersection of the two planes is $(x, y, z) = (13t+16, -11t-8, t)$

But now I don't know how to account for the line segment's ends.

How would I continue, and is there a better method?

Thanks

Comment: For endpoints, find where the lines through light source and each end of the segment meet the plane (or the line you found, which is a bit more work). Come to think of it, find those two points in the first place then create your line segment on the plane from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment, we can do as follows.

Since the line segment ends at $(3, 1, 2)$ and $(0, 2, 4)$, we can construct two lines from the light source, which will be the edges of our "shadow".

These, namely, are
$$\text{line1}(t) = \langle 3t, t, 8-6t \rangle$$
$$\text{line2}(t) = \langle 0, 2t, 8-4t \rangle$$

We solve for the intersection of the plane by substituting the entire line into the plane equation and solving for $t$, which give us $t=\frac32\Longleftrightarrow (\frac92, \frac32, -1)$ for line $1$ and $t=\frac{12}5 \Longleftrightarrow (0, \frac{24}5, -\frac85)$ for line $2$.

Parameterizing this gives
$$\text{shadow}(t) = \left\langle \frac92 - \frac92 t, \frac32 + \frac{33}{10} t, -1-\frac35 t\right\rangle$$
for $0<= t<= 1$

Comment: [+1] But you should give names in order **one follows in a better way** your (good and direct) proof :  $A,B$ for the endpoints of initial line segment and $A',B'$ for the image of this line segment by the central projection. Besides, it should also be said that the image of a line segment [A,B] by a central projection f is $[f(A),f(B)]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the feedback. I'll keep this in mind for the future :)